# Python pick up file output after reconnecting to server?

Tags: python, terminal, server

I don't have a lot of experience with python so I'm hoping somebody can help me out.

I have set up a server with some python file that I run via the commandline by doing something like:

```
python pyserver.py
```

This file provides me with continuous output so I can see what is going on. This works fine, but whenever I disconnect from my server and reconnect I can no longer see the output that this file is generating.

How can I pick up on the output of this file that I am running with python so I can see its output again after I reconnect to my server?

Comment: Hard to tell without having any implementation details

Comment: @M.Klugerford what do you need exactly?